# I have table in Ext js and I need to write some logic in <td> tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, extjs

'{overdue}' , overdue is boolean type, how can I write some logic  { here ... } ? something like this {overdue ? "yes":"no"} , but it doesnt work

Comment: Could you mark this as answer @shako davitashvili

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.application({
name : 'SwarmXTemplateExample2',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
        fullscreen: true,
        data: [
            { isDog: true, name: 'spot' },
            { isDog: false, name: 'jasper' },
            { isDog: true, name: 'gram' },
            { isDog: false, name: 'alex' },
            { isDog: false, name: 'snowball' }
        ],
        itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            
            '<tpl if="values.isDog">Yes  <tpl else> No </tpl>',
            {
                doNameCasing: function (name) {
                  return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        )
    })
   }
 });
```